# reinstalling vista product key

Tags: windows-vista, product-key, windows-activation

I recently formatted my laptop which came with Vista preinstalled and installed Windows 7 on the primary partition. I've now installed Vista on a different partition, but it won't activate my valid product key. I've looked around on here and have seen similar issues being raised, but I don't have the telephonic activation option (only option I have is online activation). I am located in South Africa.

When I enter my product key from my sticker it says it is not valid, so I must either try to activate online again or buy a different product key. I have reinstalled Vista on the primary partition several times and activated the key without a problem. This is the first time I am installing it on a different partition.

Comment: Sounds like you may need to call Microsoft, they may have flagged the key due to so many activations.

Comment: I've only done it about 4 times before, and according to the help files, I can activate as many times as needed as long as it's on the same hardware.

Comment: Vista activation phone# 1-866-740-1256

Comment: Is it possible you used the wrong Vista media? product keys are tied to version (home, pro etc) and distribution, OEM Retail, MSDN

Comment: @Arabella - Follow the directions to manually activate your installation this is your only choice.  This involves calling a number and getting the activation approved.

Comment: I'm from South Africa, is this why the telephone activation option is not showing in my activation options?

Comment: @Arabella - you should edit that last comment into your question - it's a really important factor in finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

See here [What is the Activation number for SA](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-windows_install/what-is-the-telephone-line-for-windows-activation/5428f0d9-9a45-479a-af4f-04e4760d2b04).

> try 0801 43 43 43 or
>   +27 11 361 7000